# How to create an SSL Socket in D?

Tags: sockets, ssl, d

How can I create an SSL Socket in D? I have looked a bit around in the Phobos library but there doesn't seem to be any support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phobos doesn't support it. The way I do it is to use the openssl C library.

The openssl binding package is available here:
https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/openssl

I just slapped this file together that uses the C OpenSSL library to subclass Phobos' Socket:
https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/blob/master/sslsocket.d

This code only works for a client, but it is pretty easy to use and shows how you can access the C library to do more (look up the C docs - you can call the same functions in D). At the bottom of the file is a demo main() that loads from a local https server to test it.